# Changing menu font

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I have a handle to a Menu .
I can change the text of each menu item by using API

```
SetMenuItemInfo
```

Now some of the menu's are in bold. I want to change their font to regular.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: "I have a handle to a Menu that is owned by some other application."  I am really surprised that this would/could work.

Answer (score 0):

Bold entries in a menu are the default entries (if the menu is not completely ownerdrawn).

You can change this [SetMenuDefaultItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647996%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You can ask any window to change its font by sending it `WM_SETFONT`. (Which may not work for menu's, not sure.)

You can use an [owner-drawn menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647558%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items) to have full control over its appearance.

Comment: okay I can send message WM_SETFONT to menu window and then how can I set the text.
I used SetMeuItemInfo after sending WM_SETFONT but its not working.

Comment: Use `MFT_STRING` in the `MENUITEMINFO` struct.

Comment: A menu isn't a window though so I doubt this is going to work.